# Returning data on POST in django-tastypie

Tags: django, post, tastypie

I consider it a standard that an object-creating function returns the newly created object.

So, any idea how do you do that in tastypie? When I send the POST request, the object is created, I get nothing in response, though. What I would like is to receive the JSON form of the newly created object (or at least the PK).

I tried overriding the `dehydrate` method, but it seems that it's not even called when it comes to POST.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Can't believe the answer was so easy.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#always-return-data

Just add `always_return_data = True` to your `Meta`.

Comment: also note that it doesn't return nothing, it returns a 204 with a location header, which might be nicer to your clients, depending on the amount of data, and who is providing the bulk of that data.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the the location header. I still believe though, that it's better for "create" method to return the created object.

Comment: I agree halish, one less call to the api in certain circumstances

Comment: Is there a way to get tastypie to return https instead of http in the Location header?