# Tastypie Django POST error

Tags: django, http, tastypie

I use Tastypie for Django's API. but it returns error.
my code is bellow.

```
$.ajax({
      type : "POST", 
      url : "http://192.168.1.130:8000/api/user/author/", 
      data : '{"first_name": "111","second_name": "222"}', 
      success: function(){
        alert('Submit Success')
      },
      dataType : 'json', 
      contentType : 'application/json',
      processData: false
    });
```

my api.py like this:

```
class AuthorResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Author.objects.all()
        resource_name ='author'
        fields = ['first_name','last_name']
        filtering = {
            'first_name': ALL,
        }
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

it returns 200 and post nothing.How can I reslove it?

Comment: why do you have processData set to false? 200 is a successfull http response

Comment: You should indent your code four spaces so that it is shown in a nice way. 200 is successful status code, an author object should be created, check if it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dupe of [Returning data on POST in django-tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138169/returning-data-on-post-in-django-tastypie).

Add `always_return_data = True` to your Resource meta

Answer (score 0):

If object created successfully, the object uri will be shown in Location field in response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the url be http://192.168.1.130:8000/api/author/ instead of http://192.168.1.130:8000/api/user/author/