# Tastypie -- How to make obj_create send the newly created entity back?

Tags: ajax, django, tastypie

Im sending a POST that creates a new simple `Resource` (not a ModelResource), and that works.

My question is how do I get back for example the created resource's `bundle` property to the ajax response?

That's the resource example :

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    x = fields.CharField(attribute='x')
    y = fields.CharField(attribute='y')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'myresource'
        object_class = XYObject
        authorization   = Authorization()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        x = bundle.data["x"]
        x = bundle.data["y"]
        bundle.obj = XYObject(x, y)
        return bundle
```

And this is the POST request

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '/api/v1/myresource/',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               data: data,
               dataType: 'json',
               processData: false,
               success: function(response)
               {
                //get my resource here
               },
               error: function(response){
                   $("#messages").show('error');
                 }
               });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just add `always_return_data = True` to your Meta. You'll then get a `202` with serialized data instead of the normal `201`.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138745/931277

Here are the docs: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#always-return-data

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I'm not going to save data via this `Resource`, it's an ajax-based business logic resource that should apply some controls,

I prefer to raise an `ImmediateHttpResponse`, so that I can specify the HttpResponse type like this :

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle.data['results'] = bundle.obj.check(request)
    if bundle.data['results']['valid']:
         raise ImmediateHttpResponse(self.create_response(request, bundle,response_class = HttpCreated))
    raise ImmediateHttpResponse(self.create_response(request,  bundle.data['results']['message'],response_class = HttpBadRequest))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tastypie makes use of the `post_list`(1) method. That method calls your `obj_create` method. It then returns a `201 Created`HTTP response, and the Location header is set. So, to make the long story short, you should check the headers returned by the API call and check for the  `Location` header.

**EDIT:**

Some code is useful:

```
...
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
    // You must look for Location
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
...
```

(1) https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1244

Comment: In fact, I'm not going to save data with this resource. It's just useful to some ajax-based business logic

Comment: Uhm, that's weird. Then you should return a response with content. By default, Tastypie respond with empty-responses content. Why don't you update your question with more information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919248/tastypie-how-to-make-obj-create-send-the-newly-created-entity-back/12924239#12924239

Comment: I hope you understand you're not using REST in the proper maner.